# Syntax error in Tic Tac Toe while assigning names

Tags: python-3.x

So I was writing a code on python for a Tic Tac Toe game for 2 players and I got an error while assigning variables for player names. I can't find the error.

```
import os
import time
import random

# Define the board
board = [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "]
#Define the print_board function
def print_board():
    print ("   |   |  ")
    print (" "+board[1]+" | "+board[2]+" | "+board[3]+" ")
    print ("   |   |  ")
    print ("---|---|---")
    print ("   |   |  ")
    print (" "+board[4]+" | "+board[5]+" | "+board[6]+" ")
    print ("   |   |  ")
    print ("---|---|---")
    print ("   |   |  ")
    print (" "+board[7]+" | "+board[8]+" | "+board[9]+" ")
    print ("   |   |  ")

os.system("clear")
print(a)
print_board()


n1=str(input("Enter Player 1 name")
n2=str(input("Enter Player 2 name")
b=str(input("Choose your symbol")

if b== "X" or "x":
    choice = input("Please select the place for your symbol X")
    board(choice) = "X"
```

I keep getting error on n2 variable saying the syntax is wrong.

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket in all the assignments

Comment: Count how many braces you have on the `input` lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    n1=str(input("Enter Player 1 name"))
    n2=str(input("Enter Player 2 name"))
    b=str(input("Choose your symbol"))
```